# C++ Address of class instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, instance

I have a List of Student class. In each Student there is a class-member which is a pointer University class (base class for every university classes). When building the list I want for all students of same university to point the same instance of their university.

Is there any way to get address of instance of class without accessing it directly?
And how can I check if instance of some class have been constructed?

Comment: You have a terrible typo in your class name.

Comment: @userXXX That type of school is called a "university", not a "univercity".

Answer (score 0):

You need a container class that knows about the instances of the class it contains. So to know if there's already an instance of the class with particular characteristics, you ask the container. The container can create one if it doesn't exist or it can leave that to calling code. There are a number of containers in the C++ standard library. You may want an `unordered_map` or, if you don't want the additional complexity, a `map`.

Comment: do you mean like hash map when you say map?

Comment: @user3126715 An unordered map is a hash map. A map is more like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this, one simple way can be to make the constructor of University private and have a static function that takes university name (or some other identifier) and returns the pointer to the University class.

The function can use a `map` internally to keep track that if the university name is not in the map create a new instance put it in the map and return it, otherwise return the existing instance.

Comment: So you mean that i need to just to scan my list if there is already instance of some univercity and if not to initiate one like this?

Comment: @user3126715 Yes, pretty much it. But for scanning list to check existence of university, if you use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), it will be simple and efficient.